# How to correctly use entitymanager for creating entity objects?

Tags: java, entity-framework, jpa

Good day,

I am currently on my first JPA project and I have some difficulties with using and understanding entity manager. I have created several classes and assigned them as entities via annotations. For now, I am trying to create a class which will create an entity object via entityManager. For instance, I have the following class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "product")
public class Product implements DefaultProduct {

@Id
@Column(name = "product_name", nullable = false)
private String productName;

@Column(name = "product_price", nullable = false)
private double productPrice;

@Column(name = "product_quantity", nullable = false)
private int productQuantity;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "Product_Account", nullable = false)
private Account parentAccount;

public Product(String productName, double productPrice,
        int productQuantity, Account parentAccount)
        throws IllegalArgumentException {

    if (productName == null || productPrice == 0 || productQuantity == 0) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                "Product name/price or quantity have not been specified.");
    }
    this.productName = productName;
    this.productPrice = productPrice;
    this.productQuantity = productQuantity;
    this.parentAccount = parentAccount;
}

public String getProductName() {
    return productName;
}

public double getPrice() {
    return productPrice * productQuantity;
}

public int getQuantity() {
    return productQuantity;
}

public Account getAccount() {
    return parentAccount;
}

}
```

Now, I am trying to create this class:

```
public class CreateProduct {

private static final String PERSISTENCE_UNIT_NAME = "Product";

EntityManagerFactory factory = Persistence
        .createEntityManagerFactory(PERSISTENCE_UNIT_NAME);

public void createProduct(Product product) {
    EntityManager manager = factory.createEntityManager();
    manager.getTransaction().begin();

//code to be written here

    manager.getTransaction().commit();

}
}
```

Can you please give me an example of code that I have to write down between begin() and commit() lines inside my createProduct method; additionally, I would appreciate if you could explain how entitymanager works. I have read several docs about this but still I need some clarification.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 Account account - new Account();
 Product product = new Product("name", 10, 11, account);
 manager.persist(product);
```

Depending when you put your annotations like @Column @OneToOne and others on the fields or getters entityManager will use this way to gets a field values from class. It uses reflection to read annotations and by using this knows what the table should looks like. By knowing the table structure it just creates a query in the background ind sends its to the db. Basically analysis of the classes is done when you are creating an entity manager factory and this operation in general is very time consuming (depends on the db structure). To understend deaply how it works read more about reflection. If you get reflection you will get how simple it is.

Comment: Thank you for your reply Marek. In my case, account is also an entity; will it cause any conflict if I will create an account instance within my createProduct() method?

Comment: should be done the same way as Product (@Entity and others). EM is so smart and can handle this :) Remember to put both of the classes in persistence.xml

Comment: Cheers mate! That gave me some explanation on what is going on :D